# Web Site HTML Cutting Off Bottom of Screen

Tags: html, css, flash

After Much Searching I am still unable to find a solution to my problem. I have created two websites. One Flash Based [www.riverviewhurricanes.org](http://www.riverviewhurricanes.org)     and one HTML based [www.golfcartsuncity.com](http://www.golfcartsuncity.com). Both of The Websites Cutoff at the Bottom when viewed on a widescreen. I will post source or java script when someone replies but I'm a noob just starting out and not sure if i change in the index source style.js or layout.css or ie.css. Let me know what source i should post so that you may help me out in the most efficient manner.Both of these sites are live and I appreciate all of the help in advance. Thank you so much and I look forward to your reply.

Comment: the content is quite high. and looks ok on chrome.

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.  For those that monitor the remaining tags, you might want to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems with the Golf site. However, with the Flash site, the issue is that the table with the Flash in it is set to 100% and you have a div above it that's 24px high. So 24px is always cut off, causing scrolling.

Reduce the table height to accommodate the G+ bar, or lay it over the table. One method to do this is to add `position: absolute;` to that div.